# How can I eliminate whitespace on one side of the mobile viewport?

Tags: mobile, overflow, whitespace, padding

**Hello!** First time posting but a user since a year ago.

I usually hit up my friends for assistance, but this one has them a bit stumped / it's time I try this community out.

My issue: the client I'm working for wants to see the Images/content sit flush against the right hand side of screen. Fair enough, too!

For the example of 'micro padding' please see:

[Cargo site](https://henrykingcreative.com)

I've looked for assistance and tried to add in code under body, html (overflow-x: hidden), but gained no result. [image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1apYl.png)